# onload event is ignored in chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have created a chrome app in body tag's onload event it calls a function that shows an alert. When I run the app's main page as a web page it works fine. But it does not show any clue of an alert when I run it as a chrome app. (other things works as usual). can someone tell me what the is wrong here.

Comment: What happens if you use `jQuery(document).ready(function(){/*your functionhere*/});`

Answer (score 1):

First, `alert` is actually disabled for chrome packaged apps (you can see a message about this if you try it from the developer console).

Second, inline javascript is disabled due to CSP, so you cannot do `<body onload="..jscode..">` (assuming you did that based on your description).

Instead, from your main app window, load a local javascript file: `<script src="my.js"></script>`, and in it add something like:

```
// Inside my.js:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log('here');
  // Still cannot use alert() but you can manipulate your window in other ways.
});
```